# SVG icons not rendering in TypeScript React component bundled as node module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

I wrote a node module containing a Typescript React component I want to include in several other projects. The component project is based on create-react-app. The component includes some SVGs that are rendered as components using the `import { ReactComponent as Icon } from 'path/to/my/component.svg';` syntax [explained in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files). The component is rendered in a test page as part of the module project, where the SVG icons render fine.

However, when I bundle the module and include it in another project, the component renders, but without all the icons. The console tells me that all icon components imported now are `undefined`. I guess the problem could lie with webpack, but have no idea how to fix it. Also, I would rather not eject the create-react-app project for reasons unrelated to the problem.

### Results of my investigation

- I am positive that the distributed bundle contains all the icons and the relative paths are correct
- The component is compiled to JS using tsc. When copying the distrubution folder with the JS code into another project and importing the component from there, the icons render a-okay
- When using `yarn pack` to create a package and installing is as dependency in another project, the icons are gone

### Condition

- I would prefer not have to eject the component project in order to edit the `webpack.config`

### package.json of the module project

```
{
  "name": "MyFancyComponent",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "husky": "^2.4.1",
    "i18next": "^17.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "test-name": "./test-name-v1.0.0.tgz",
    "test-name2": "./test-name2-v1.0.1.tgz",
    "typescript": "3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.15",
    "@types/node": "12.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "@types/react-i18next": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "files": [
    "/dist",
    "/style",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dist": "tsc && cp -r src/lib/style/* dist/style && cp -r src/lib/tenants/* dist/tenants"
  }
}
```

### tsconfig of the module project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src/lib",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/@types", "src/lib"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.*"]
}
```

A type definition for .svg files is also included and defined as follows:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import * as React from 'react';

    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;

    const src: string;
    export default src;
}
```

### How SVGs are inluded in my components

#### Component Wrapper

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from 'pat/to/component.svg';

export default (props: any) => (
    <i>
        <Icon />
    </i>
);
```

#### Using the icon

```
import React from 'react';
import IconComponent from './icons/icon-component';

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
    <div>
         <IconComponent />
    </div>
);
```

Any ideas on how to go about to solve this?

Comment: same problem here, opened and issue/question on svgr  
https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/494